# Wait for user input in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm doing a simple snake game and I want to show score and wait for click/touch before starting new game.

I've tried:

```
while self.paused:
    pass
```

And put `self.paused = False` in `on_touch_down()`. It freezes (not really surprising).

So is there some better way to wait for user input? (Or some other aproach.)

Comment: I don't entirely understand the context but another way of pausing the game is excepting a keyboard interrupt. With that you could pause (and unpause) the 'game' by pressing CTRL + C

Comment: @ThomasWagenaar AFAIK that's for cmd line, right? (this is gui/nui app) But to be honest, I'm not really sure the question makes sense.

Comment: I hope the question makes more sense after the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it with different aproach.

I added `game_over` variable and I set to `True` on game over. My `on_touch_down()` code changed to this:

```
if self.game_over:
    self.game_over = False
    self.game.start_new_game()
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i did something similar a year ago. Your approach works but i think sometimes you want a specific key to be pressed by the user.

My approach was to use PyUserInput [PyUserInput](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput).

An example from the documentation:

```
from pymouse import PyMouse
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard

m = PyMouse()
k = PyKeyboard()

# pressing a key
k.press_key('H')

#Create an Alt+Tab combo
k.press_key(k.alt_key)
k.tap_key(k.tab_key)
k.release_key(k.alt_key)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's interesting but the app is mainly for Android.

Comment: Actually, now that i think about it, your method works well. This method worked well when i was trying to simulate a entered key.